# Laravel 5.4 Combined Api route group with auth middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

How do I combine the api route group with my auth to have something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { 
   ... 
});
```

Thus if I call the default api route:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) { 
     return $request->user(); 
});

app/api/user
```

I get no return value.

I am new to api routes so what am I doing wrong.

I could not found a tutorial for api Laravel 5.4

Comment: What are you trying to combine ?

Comment: @EddyTheDove like trying to check in the api Group if the user is authentificated

Comment: Try dumping the `$request->user()` rather than returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
   Route::get('user', function(Request $request) {
       dd($request->user());
   });
});
```

Passing your token via ajax

```
var token = <?php json_encode(Auth::user()->api_token); ?>;
$.ajax({
    url:'http://...',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    method: 'POST'
    ...
})
```

Comment: I will check this out do you know why I don't get a return value?

Comment: It really depends on your criteria. Is the user connected on the browser where you send the request from. If not, are you sending a token in the headers?

Comment: 401 means the user is not authorized. Are you passing the user's token ?

Comment: Nope how do I pass that in Ajax?

Comment: If I use the same route in my web.php(route) it works it just does not work in the api.php(route file)

Comment: Check my update. It works on the web because on the web the user is already authenticated in the session. In your api, user is authenticated during every single request.

Comment: The Ajax function is inside my app.js I can't put php in it, what would you do rename it to app.blade.php ? But then laravel mix wont work I think

Comment: No need to. In the file where you call app.js you can declare that token variable before you call app.js. It will be available to your app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140086/discussion-between-micheasl-and-eddythedove).

Comment: Hi mate, if my answer and comments helped you in any sort, please don't forget to mark my answer or upvote me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function () { 
     return Auth::user(); 
});
```

or

```
Route::get('/user', function () { 
         return Auth::user(); 
})->middleware('auth');
```